# Whether to use GraphQL query or mutation for sending external messages

Tags: graphql, vue-apollo

I understand that a GraphQL mutation is for a request that modifies server state. What about a request that does not change any server state, but sends a message, like an email, to an external client or service. In designing a GraphQL API, which is more appropriate for this type of request: a query, or a mutation?

On [GraphQL's learning website](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/) it gives this explanation of mutations:

> In REST, any request might end up causing some side-effects on the server, but by convention it's suggested that one doesn't use GET requests to modify data. GraphQL is similar - technically any query could be implemented to cause a data write. However, it's useful to establish a convention that any operations that cause writes should be sent explicitly via a mutation.

In [The June 2018 Spec for GraphQL](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/) it defines the basic GraphQL operations as the following:

> - query – a read‐only fetch.
> - mutation – a write followed by a fetch.
> - subscription – a long‐lived request that fetches data in response to source events.

Since sending a message doesn't modify server state, it first seemed appropriate to use a query. However, for front-end frameworks for GraphQL such as [Vue Apollo](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#simple-query), queries are most naturally implemented as automatically updating, idempotent, read-only fetches of data. Sending a message is not idempotent; I only want to do it once.

Comment: The difference is largely academic, although there are a few practical differences between queries and mutations outlined in the linked post. As a rule of thumb, if we're talking about an *action* that's done by a user or client, it should be a mutation.